# Python fastest n needles to n haystacks string replacing

Tags: python, string, algorithm, search, replace

So here is what I need to do.

Dumbed down version:

In list A replace **every** occurrence of substring from list B with the underscored version of the substring.

I have a class called Folder() that holds data.

```
class Folder():
    dataset= [('question sentence', 'multiple word answer'),... n times]

    list_of_answers=['answer','multiple_word_answer',... n times]





def insert_answers(folder):

    temp_dataset=[]
    for q,a in folder.dataset:
        for answer in folder.list_of_answers:
            #If answer is more than one word
            if len(answer.split())>1:
                answer_split=answer.split('(')
                #Only use the first part of split and strip it of whitespaces
                answer_split=answer_split[0].strip()
                answer_=answer.replace(' ','_')
                q=q.replace(answer_split,answer_)
        temp_dataset.append([q,a])

    folder.dataset=temp_dataset
```

As you can see this is very slow as I have about 435 000 question sentences
and several thousand answers in list_of_answers

I need the q,a pairs to remain together.

I am going to multiprocess this for about 144 processing cores to make it faster but I'd like to find a faster algorithm.

Example input:

```
questions=['pablo picasso painted guernica and random occurence of andy warhol so the question makes sense','andy warhol was born on ...']
list_of_answers=['pablo picasso','andy warhol (something)']
```

Output:

```
questions=['pablo_picasso painted guernica and random occurence of andy_warhol_(something) so the question makes sense','andy_warhol_(something) was born on ...']
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are after. Can you provide an example input and your expected output? Do `dataset` and `list_of_answers` match up element-wise? Are the elements in `dataset` keys where `list_of_answers` are values to do a map-type replacement?

Comment: @Cyber added example

Comment: Why do you split on `(`?

Comment: What should the output be if `'picasso painted'` were also in `list_of_answers`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Wikipedia Titles sometimes include () for example Pablo Picasso (Painter), but in the text it is only Pablo Picasso and I need to replace it with Pablo_Picasso_(Painter)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straight-forward implementation using a regular expression. It solves your example test case, though I'm not sure how efficient it is for your large real data. Also doesn't handle overlapping matches (yet), but you didn't clarify yet how to handle those.

Test case:

```
questions=['pablo picasso painted guernica and random occurence of andy warhol so the question makes sense','andy warhol was born on ...']
list_of_answers=['pablo picasso','andy warhol']
desired = ['pablo_picasso painted guernica and random occurence of andy_warhol so the question makes sense','andy_warhol was born on ...']
```

Solution:

```
import re
finder = r'\b(' + '|'.join(list_of_answers) + r')\b'
def underscorer(match):
    return match.group().replace(' ', '_')
output = [re.sub(finder, underscorer, question) for question in questions]
```

Test:

```
>>> output == desired
True
```

Comment: well this eliminated the need to cycle through one of the lists which is nice, would be nice to know the efficiency though and need to adapt it to the input insert_answer() function

Comment: @Kameegaming Can you test it and tell how fast it is with your data?

Comment: not in any effective way, the problem with this solution is that it doesn't take into account the parantheses

Comment: @Kameegaming Yeah but a speed test could at least tell already whether the approach is fast enough. No use trying to make it "correct" if it's not going to be fast enough anyway.

Comment: there shouldn't be any overlapping matches or the longest possible match is used